Contained pull image from different repositories
I need to pull an image from different repositories
I am using below to pull the image
root@master-node:~# sudo ctr images pull registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8: resolving      |--------------------------------------|
elapsed: 0.4 s             total:   0.0 B (0.0 B/s)
ctr: failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": unexpected status from HEAD request to https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.8: 403 Forbidden
root@master-node:~

I need to load the exact image from different repository like below
--image-repository=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers
How I can do above with containerd?
